# Stop Scrapy from logging spider output to Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, logging, scrapy

Whenever I run my spider `scrapy crawl test -O test.json` in my Visual Studio Code terminal I get output like this:

```
2023-01-31 14:31:45 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.example.com/product/1
{'price': 100,
 'newprice': 90
}
2023-01-31 14:31:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-01-31 14:31:50 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (251 items) in: test.json
2023-01-31 14:31:50 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://localhost:61169/session/996866d968ab791730e4f6d87ce2a1ea {}
2023-01-31 14:31:50 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:61169 "DELETE /session/996866d968ab791730e4f6d87ce2a1ea HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2023-01-31 14:31:50 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Remote response: status=200 | data={"value":null} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '14', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
2023-01-31 14:31:50 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2023-01-31 14:31:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 91321,
 'downloader/request_count': 267,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 267,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2730055,
 'downloader/response_count': 267,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 267,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 121,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 11.580893,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 31, 13, 31, 50, 495392),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 9718676,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 267,
 'item_scraped_count': 251,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 537,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 267,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 267,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 267,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 267,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 267,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 31, 13, 31, 38, 914499)}
2023-01-31 14:31:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I want to log all this, including the `print('hi')` lines in my Spider but I DON'T want the spider output logged, in this case `{'price': 100, 'newprice': 90 }`.

Inspecting the above I think I need to disable only the `downloader/response_bytes`.
I've been reading this https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html, but I'm not sure where or how to configure my exact use case. I have hundreds of spiders and I don't want to have to add a configuration in each, but rather apply the loggin config to all spiders. Do I need to add a separate config file or add to an existing like `scrapy.cfg`?

**UPDATE 1**

So here's my folder structure where I created `settings.py`:

```
Scrapy\
    tt_spiders\
        myspiders\
            spider1.py
            spider2.py
            settings.py
        middlewares.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
    scrapy.cfg
    settings.py
```

**settings.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    disable_list = ['scrapy.core.engine', 'scrapy.core.scraper', 'scrapy.spiders']
    for element in disable_list:
        logger = logging.getLogger(element)
        logger.disabled = True

    spider = 'example_spider'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

This throws 3 errors, which makes sense as I have not defined these:

- "logging" is not defined
- "get_project_settings" is not defined
- "CrawlerProcess" is not defined

But more importantly, what I don't understand, this code contains `spider = 'example_spider'`,
where I want this logic to apply to ALL spiders.

So I reduced it to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    disable_list = ['scrapy.core.scraper']
```

But still the output is logged. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that we have this spider:

spider.py:

```py
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/text()').get()
        yield item
```

And its output is:

```py
...
[scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/>
{'title': 'Long-sleeved Jersey Top', 'price': '$12.99'}
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 329,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
...
```

If you want to disable logging for specific line then just copy the text inside the square brackets and disable its logger.
e.g.: `[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/>`.

main.py:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    disable_list = ['scrapy.core.engine', 'scrapy.core.scraper', 'scrapy.spiders']
    for element in disable_list:
        logger = logging.getLogger(element)
        logger.disabled = True

    spider = 'example_spider'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

If you want to disable some of the extensions you can set them to `None` in `settings.py`:

```py
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.telnet': None,
    'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats': None,
    'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats': None
}
```

**Update 1:**

Add just this to `settings.py`:

```py
import logging
disable_list = ['scrapy.core.engine', 'scrapy.core.scraper', 'scrapy.spiders']
for element in disable_list:
    logger = logging.getLogger(element)
    logger.disabled = True
```

Comment: Thank you! The first part of your answer (starting with `if __name__ == "__main__":` ) seems to be what I need. In which file would I add that block so it applies to all spiders?

Comment: @Adam either `main.py` or `settings.py`.

Comment: Thank you again. I added update 1, if you could have a look?

Comment: @Adam. I'm using `__name__ == "__main__"` because I added it to my main file. For `setting.py` just add the code that disables the loggers.

Comment: Thanks. It still does not work. I've added a "settings.py" file on each folder level (see my updated folder structure above) with just a single line `disable_list = ['scrapy.core.scraper'] `. What am I missing?

Comment: @Adam There's no need for multiple settings files. Just copy the code in my answer from `Update 1` to your `settings.py` file. Copy it as is with the import, the list, and the loop.

Comment: Great, I'll try that. At what level should I keep the `settings.py` file? In the same folder as my spider files? Or a level up? Or another level up? (sorry am new to this)

Comment: One level up from the spider. (You can create a project with `scrapy startproject project_name` and see where all the files should be).